# Spark - Group on one Column and find Mean of other colums

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate, grouping

I Have some data with 4 columns (c1, c2, c3 and c4) and have got it in a RDD via some scala code.

I want to group/bin by c1 and find mean of c2 and mean of c3 as well as c4 in each of the c1 groups.

I'm looking at RDD:reduceByKey, but I haven't managed to to understand exactly how it to be used. Is there a Better way to do this? How can I do this from the Scala API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say you have a `DataFrame`, so you probably shouldn't use the `RDD` API (which is often less efficient, and in this case probably less intuitive either) - here's a solution using the `DataFrame` API:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val result = df.groupBy("c1").agg(mean("c2"), mean("c3"), mean("c4"))
```

`result` would be a DataFrame with the following schema (assuming `c1` is a String to begin with):

```
root
 |-- c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- avg(c2): double (nullable = true)
 |-- avg(c3): double (nullable = true)
 |-- avg(c4): double (nullable = true)
```

**EDIT**:

in case the list of columns is dynamic, you can easily map such a list into a list of corresponding "means" and aggregate the DF using that list:

```
val colsToCompute = List("c2", "c3", "c4") // can be loaded dynamically
val means: Seq[Column] = colsToCompute.map(mean)
val result = df.groupBy("c1").agg(means.head, means.tail: _*)
```

For completeness - here's a solution using **RDD** API, but:

- It's much less concise
- It's much harder to "generify" for a dynamic number of columns
- It might perform worse

There might be slightly shorter implementations, but not much simpler:

```
val rdd: RDD[(String, Int, Int, Int)] = ...

val result: RDD[(String, (Double, Double, Double))] = rdd
  .keyBy(_._1)
  .mapValues { case (k, v1, v2, v3) => (1, v1, v2, v3) } // add base for counter
  .reduceByKey { case ((a1, a2, a3, a4), (b1, b2, b3, b4)) => (a1+b1, a2+b2, a3+b3, a4+b4) } // sum counter and values
  .mapValues { case (count, v1, v2, v3) => (v1.toDouble/count, v2.toDouble/count, v3.toDouble/count) } // calculate means
```

Comment: While I do have a Dataframe right now, I'm looking at doing it via RDD because finally the data would be dynamic. It could have 4 columns or 3 columns; The program would figure out how many columns to Mean, by looking at a config file.

Comment: "finally the data would be dynamic. It could have 4 columns or 3 columns" - this too is easier to do with DataFrame... I'll update my answer accordingly